# Kill PIDs created in while loop background processes

Tags: bash

So I have a while loop which loops over a text file which contains names, then performs a background process on the list. This works all fine and well, but when it's over, I need to ctrl-c out of it. How can I perform a SIGINT once all of the processes are completed so I don't have to ctrl-c?

Would I need to do it on each individual process? Or can I do it on the loop by using something like sleep?

This is what I currently have, but doesn't quite work.

`while read BAR; do foo $BAR & done < bars.txt; pid=$!; wait; kill pid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're collecting only the *last* PID, not the PIDs of *all* your background processes.

If you collect the PIDs, you can wait on them individually -- which lets you check whether the individual jobs failed, *or* to see which one of them isn't actually finishing:

```
pids=( )
while read bar; do
  foo "$bar" & pids+=( "$!" )
done < bars.txt

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  echo "Checking exit status of $pid..."
  if wait "$pid"; then
    echo "$pid succeeded!"
  else
    echo "$pid failed!"
  fi
done
```

---

If you want to track down which specific *values* processing succeeded or failed for, you can do even better (with bash 4.0 or later):

```
declare -A pids=( )
while read -r bar; do
  foo "$bar" & pids[$!]="$bar"
done < bars.txt

for pid in "${!pids[@]}"; do
  bar=${pids[$pid]}
  echo "Checking exit status of $pid (processing value $bar)..."
  if wait "$pid"; then
    echo "$pid (for $bar) succeeded!"
  else
    echo "$pid (for $bar) failed!"
  fi
done
```

---

In either of the above cases, each invocation of `wait` is responsible for returning after the corresponding PID has exited. Thus, when all your background tasks have exited, your script will exit on its own.

---

Finally, to *force* your children to exit, you can build a signal handler that takes advantage of the PID list:

```
shutdown() { kill "${pids[@]}"; } # or "${!pids[@]}" for the second example
trap shutdown 0
```

Comment: Not that I should do this, but is there anyway to do this in a 'one liner' so I don't have to execute a file? Like could I put the wait in the loop then kill the pid? Or would this just make it all synchronous again?

Comment: Backing up for a moment -- why the `kill`s at all? As I read the question, your background processes exit on their own, and the only problem was that the script that invoked them wasn't exiting... right?

Comment: If you want a one-liner that handles parallel processes, btw, you're probably better off with either `xargs -P` or GNU parallel. For example, to run a maximum of 16 processes at a time: `xargs -d $'\n' -P 16 foo <bars.txt`

Comment: The background processes didn't exit on their own - I was calling ffmpeg on multiple files from a text file. After reading over the logs, as you said, only the last one was exiting. A shell file's fine, but I'll probably check those out just to cross all my t's and dot my i's. Thanks for this in depth response

Comment: With that clarification -- you certainly can kill them now that you have the list of PIDs (`kill "${pids[@]}"` or `kill "${!pids[@]}"`, depending on whether you're following the first pattern -- storing PIDs as values -- or the latter, storing them as indices).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel -j0 foo {} < bars.txt
echo $? jobs failed
```

If you leave out `-j0` it will run one job per CPU core.

If you need to know exactly which jobs failed, you can use a joblog:

```
parallel --joblog jl -j0 foo {} < bars.txt
cat jl
```

It also makes sure the output from different jobs are not mixed together, so if you use the output you are guaranteed that you will not get half-a-line from two different jobs.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

You should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one-liner, you could build it around the following logic (formatted for better readability).

```
while -r read BAR
do
  foo "$BAR" &
done < bars.txt
wait
```

This will wait for all background tasks to finish (including any background task launched prior to executing this command).  It is a bit crude (CharlesDuffy has proposed a solution allowing better tracking of tasks), but it has the questionable advantage of being short enough for a one-liner.

```
while -r read BAR ; do foo "$BAR" & done < bars.txt ; wait
```

To kill the jobs right after launching them (I am unsure why you would want to do that), you can probably do something like this :

```
while -r read BAR ; do foo "$BAR" & done < bars.txt ; kill $(jobs -p)
```

Once again, this will signal all background jobs, not only those you just launched.

Comment: Unfortunately, my background processes don't exit by themselves